# Uploading to blob by PutBlockList method in C# and MD5 check

Tags: c#, azure, upload

I am trying to upload blocks of a movie to Azure blob in C# using PutBlockList method. I have been writing a test code and the problem is that when I use MD5 for the integrity of data and I purposely corrupt data, which result in a different MD5 value, the server does not reject the upload and accept it, while in a correct code it had to be rejected.

```
 var upload = Take.CommitBlocks(shot,takeId,data);
 ....
 blob.Properties.ContentMD5 = md5;
 return Task.Factory.FromAsync(blob.BeginPutBlockList(ids,null,null),blob.EndPutBlockList);
```

in my test method, I corrupt the data purposely, but the system still accept the data. How can I fix this ? In a correct code I am supposed to receive Error400, but I get nothing.

Answer (score 0):

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2011/02/18/windows-azure-blob-md5-overview.aspx. Put Block List doesn't validate the MD5, but the MD5 *is* validate individually on each Put Block call.

Answer (score 0):

I am a few years late to the party, but from what I can see, this functionality is still not built into the API and SDK (Assembly Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=8.1.4.0).  That said, here is my work around:

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

/// <summary>
/// Extension methods for <see cref="CloudBlockBlob"/>
/// </summary>
public static class CloudBlockBlobExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Attempts to open a stream to download a range, and if it fails with <see cref="StorageException"/> 
    /// then the message is compared to a string representation of the expected message if the MD5
    /// property does not match the property sent.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="instance">The instance of <see cref="CloudBlockBlob"/></param>
    /// <returns>Returns a false if the calculated MD5 does not match the existing property.</returns>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">If <paramref name="instance"/> is null.</exception>
    /// <remarks>This is a hack, and if the message from storage API changes, then this will fail.</remarks>
    public static async Task<bool> IsValidContentMD5(this CloudBlockBlob instance)
    {
        if (instance == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(instance));

        try
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await instance.DownloadRangeToStreamAsync(ms, null, null);
            }
        }
        catch (StorageException ex)
        {
            return !ex.Message.Equals("Calculated MD5 does not match existing property", StringComparison.Ordinal);
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```